# How to get selected year range in line chart drawn by highchart in react js

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I want to get year slider(i.e xAxis) year range when scrolling on line chart in highchart
Can anyone please help me?
[image: Here is the line chart]

Comment: Do you mean the navigator feature? https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator

Comment: Yes navigator feature

Comment: So here is a basuc demo of the Highstock chart in the React: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-gnev1?file=/demo.jsx